# AsyncTask starts after function is finished

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I just have a public function where I have some loops etc. and in the beginning of my function I start my AsyncTask which returns me a value which is needed in the near of the end of this function. But somehow the AsyncTask just starts after this function finished ? Is there a way to run the Asynctask before or parallel ? Until today I thought AsyncTask are normally running parallel. I found out the method

> .get()

but this is freezing the thread ... I need an alternative or fix

```
    public void my_function ()
    {
      new async_task().execute()
      ... //do something

      if (returned_value_from_async_task == 10)    //Here I need the variable which is returned in the async_task
      {
       ... //do something
      }

    } //End of function

//When I go to debug mode the AsyncTask starts right here
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Thats the "Async" part of `AsyncTask`. The code at the end of the function isn't going to wait for the task to finish. so you can't rely on that data to be there. The code you're running in your function probably takes less time than it takes the `ThreadPoolExecutor` to spool up your task.

Execute the code that depends on the data from the `AsyncTask` in `onPostExecute`

EDIT:
Without knowing what "more complex" means, it's hard to say what your best option is. But you could split the function, thusly

```
public void preExecutePrep() {
    YourTask yourTask = new YourTask();
    yourTask.execute();

    //do what you can without the result
}

private void postExecuteCode(int result) {
    if (result != 10) return;
    //do the rest
}
```

then call `postExecuteCode` in `onPostExecute`.  If this isn't going to cut it, I'll need more specific information to help

Comment: the function is more complex than this. So Im not able to put it in 'onPostExecute' .Is there not another way ?